# How to scrape the website properly and getting all td texts from website

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new to python. is anyone know {sum(int(td.text) for td in soup.select('td:last-child')[1:])} what is use of [1:] in this or [0] or [1]. i saw it in many scraping examples below for in loop. As i was practicing i build this code and don't able to scrape all data in csv file. thanks in advance, sorry for two question at one time.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url= "https://iplt20.com/stats/2020/most-runs"

r= requests.get (url)

soup= BeautifulSoup (r.content, 'html5lib')

lst= []

table=soup.find ('div', attrs = {'class':'js-table'})



#for row in table.findAll ('div', attrs= {'class':'top-players__player-name'}):
#    score = {}
 #   score['Player'] = row.a.text.strip()
#    lst.append(score)

for row in table.findAll (class_='top-players__m top-players__padded '):
    score = {}
    score['Matches'] = int(row.td.text)
    lst.append(score)

filename= 'iplStat.csv'
with open (filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
    w= csv.DictWriter(f,['Player', 'Matches'])
    w.writeheader()
    for score in lst:
        w.writerow(score)



print (lst)
```

Comment: All u have to do is to click on the green tick mark near my answer. Accepting an answer as the best answer would keep the site clean and would also help you gain 2 reputation points!!!

Comment: Done. but can you suggest how to learn coding coding.

Comment: Just watch few tutorials and solve more exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this is not even needed. Just use `pandas`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://iplt20.com/stats/2020/most-runs"

r = requests.get (url)

df = pd.read_html(r.content)[0]

df.to_csv("iplStats.csv", index = False)
```

Screenshot of `csv` file:

[image]